# Simple javascript library for visualizing a graph/network in a circle?

Tags: javascript, networking, graph, visualization

I am looking for a javascript library which plots networks with the nodes arranged in a circle.

There are some other good questions about javascript visualisation in general, but most of the things referenced seem to be quite heavyweight toolkits.  I am looking for a simple API that lets me pass in an array of string pairs representing connections, and then plots the nodes of the resulting graph in a circle, with interior lines joining the connected nodes.

Requirements: javascript (not flash), free, available for offline use

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I recently had a similar need and found that the best free graph visualization was [Javascript InfoVis Tooklit](http://thejit.org/).  I couldn't find anything more lightweight that would also display a reasonable connected graph.  Fortunately, there are a good number of examples/tutorials to learn how to set it up for your specific application.

Comment: So would my "circle of nodes" case be an instance of their HyperTree class?

Comment: I was thinking the RGraph class since it's a graph rather than a tree - but by all means, play around with the demos until you find the one closest to what you are envisioning.

Comment: Link seems to be broken leading to a non related commercial site now

Answer (score 4):

Cytoscape Web JS will do what you need.

Check out the github page [here](http://cytoscape.github.com/cytoscape.js/) which also contains a simple demo
http://cytoscape.github.com/cytoscape.js/

Comment: Is it possible to show the kind of relations? Can i put a name for each relations?

Comment: Yes of course. I answered the question [you asked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14293474/can-i-show-the-kind-of-relation-between-nodes-in-cytoscape-js/14294825#14294825)

Answer (score 1):

Take a lookat http://raphaeljs.com/

Comment: That seems to be a drawing library: I'm looking for something which will actually have a "draw_graph(data)" function rather than having to do my own circles/lines etc.

Comment: Apologies: look further at http://g.raphaeljs.com/

Comment: g.raphaeljs.com is for visualizing pie/bar charts - not a networks/graphs.

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at Google's Visualisation APIs? It's Javascript, and you can run it offline. (plus they have some tools in Python/Java for converting your data to use...etc).

Comment: From the Google Visualization API FAQ:
`Can I use visualizations offline?
No; your computer must have live access to http://www.google.com/jsapi in order to use visualizations`

Answer (score 0):

[mxGraph](http://www.jgraph.com/mxgraph.html) is free if your use is non-commercial