# Show the kind of relation between nodes in cytoscape.js

Tags: javascript, graph, cytoscape.js

I am looking for a software that allows me to draw relations between entities with automatic drawing and with user interaction. I have saw cytoscape.js and it seems like a really good option, but I want to know if with this software you can visualize the name of the relations.

The objetive of the example is to draw two persons and show their relation, for example, that they are brothers.

`Person1 ====== brother =====> Person2`

Do I need to modify the code to do this?

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to modify the code. This functionality is already built in. You will need to know how to use the [mappers](http://cytoscape.github.com/cytoscape.js/#style/mappers) and [cytoscape stylesheet definitions](http://cytoscape.github.com/cytoscape.js/#core/initialisation).

If you take a look at the source of the demo that they used [here](http://cytoscape.github.com/cytoscape.js/js/demo.js), you'll see that when you're defining the cytoscape css style, you need to set the `content` attribute which you could then use the mappers and specify which attribute in the node/edge data you'd like to display. This is already done with the `id` attribute for nodes as follows:

```
style: cytoscape.stylesheet()
  .selector("node")
        .css({
            "content": "data(id)",
            "shape": "data(shape)",
            "border-width": 3,
            "background-color": "#DDD",
            "border-color": "#555",
        })
```

You can do the exact same for edges
Hope this helps.